# CodeIgniter Routing urls for Search term SEO friendly

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem to make my search urls more SEO Friendly and none of the solutions in stackoverflow worked for me, I tried everything.

Currently my search urls are like this :
https://www.example.com/search?s=Cars&location=London,UK&lat=0.0000&lng=0.0000

I want the url to look like this

https://www.example.com/find/Cars-London,UK/0.0000/0.0000

My Search class looks like this

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
        check_installer();

        $this->load->helper('url','form');  
            $this->load->model('Home_Model');
            $this->load->model('Cars_Model');   
            $this->load->model('Search_Model');

            $this->load->dbforge();


    }   


    public function index(){    

        $this->load->view('config');
        if($this->input->post() )
        {
            echo  $this->load->view('search/tmpl/search_ajax','',true);
            die();
        }

        $data['meta_setup'] = "search";
        $this->load->view('search/search',$data);

    }
```

In routes whatever I tried it didn't work. I'm open to any suggestion to make this url SEO friendly.

Comment: Where are your routes?

Comment: @Don'tPanic In routes.php i have $route['default_controller'] = 'Home'; only I tried $route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/$1'; but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your routing controller abd manually change your route to specific uri you want 
here is a link to how to create a user friendly uri
link : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: In routes.php i have $route['default_controller'] = 'Home'; only I tried $route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/$1'; but it didn't work

Comment: I think this might help 
route :::: $route['edit/:id'] = 'contacts/edit';  
where contact is the controller and edit is the function
url ::: http://localhost/yourproject/contacts/edit/1

Note :: Do remember you need to pass the arguments in the function parameters

like: function edit($id){  //code }
you can pass as many fields as you like,

if you like you can see examples on : https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-url-routing.html